# Syncing schema privileges in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Aloha,

I'm using MySQL Workbench version 5.2.34 and have created a database model as well as users & roles in the Schema Privileges section.  My problem is that when I sync my model, the  Physical Schemata will sync, but the users and roles do not.  I've even tried to right click on the users & roles and click "copy sql to clipboard", but afterwards the clipboard is empty (it works when I copy the SQL to clipboard for any of my tables).  I've tried this in Workbench on my Windows XP machine as well as my OSX 10.6.7.  Does anybody know what my problem may be?

Mahalo,

Frank

Comment: Take a data base dump of the original and examine it.  Are the `GRANT` statements there?

Comment: I actually created a new DB to sync the model with.  The Users db did not contain the users defined in the Schema Privileges section.  When I synced the model, all of the tables in the Physical Schemata synced to the DB, but the users in the Schema Privileges section were not replicated to the MySQL Users DB.  Since they were not created I figured I could "Copy SQL to clipboard" and just paste it in the command line, but that did not produce the SQL code.  Ideally, I would think that Workbench would sync the users.  Unfortunately, I had to write the grant statements manually.

Comment: I'm wondering how to do that as well. To work around the problem, I right clicked on the user and chose "Copy SQL to Clipboard", then I pasted it into a MySQL shell session.

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose `Synchronize Model...` from the `Database` menu . Instead, choose `Forward Engineer...` from the `Database` menu. This will add users and grant them privileges.